# I want to send session data into blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a user profile with laravel! I can set the session I can see the data into the controller but now I want to compact the data for the profile blade.

```
public function profile(Request $request)
{
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
                  'email' => 'required|email',
                  'password' => 'required',
]);

 $user = DB::table('user_registers')
       ->where('email',$request->input('email'))
       ->first();

      if (!empty($user->email)) {
       if(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password))
       {
         $request->session()->put('data',$request->input('email'));
         if ($request->session()->has('data')) {
           return view('fontend.index')->with('data', $request->input('email'));
         }
       }else{
         return back()->with('password','Incorrect Password!');
       }
     }else {
       return back() ->with('email','Please Insert a valid email');
     }

    }
```

Comment: [Why not read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#using-the-session)? *You may also use the global session PHP function to retrieve and store data in the session. When the session helper is called with a single, string argument, it will return the value of that session key.* So just try `session('data')` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pass data to blade from controller you can do like this in your controller:

```
public function profile(Request $request)
{
    return view('fontend.index', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

check [Basic Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#basic-controllers) doc

but if you want pass flash data and error masseage with old data to your blade
in your blade file for feilds you can do like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
```

and for error message

```
@error('name')
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
@enderror
```

check [Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input) and [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation) doc

i hope can help you